# Angular 2 datepicker transparent

Tags: css, angular, datepicker

I added ng2-datepicker on my angular 2 app but I have issue on this.I added screen shot regarding this problem.So please help me to solve this problem.

[image]

I used z-index but It not solve my problem.Code is given below.

**component.html**

```
<div class="row form-group">
            <datepicker [expanded]="true" formControlName="connection_join_date"></datepicker>
          </div>
```

**ng2-datepicker.css**

```
.ui-kit-calendar-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 170px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  z-index: 99;
  position: relative;
  width: 170px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  z-index: 99;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container .ui-kit-calendar-input {
  border: 1px solid #aec9de;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 70px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #fcfcff;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container .ui-kit-calendar-input i {
  color: #505b71;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container .ui-kit-calendar-input.opened {
  width: 170px;
  border: 1px solid #44c8f9;
  color: #44c8f9;
  background: rgba(68, 200, 249, 0.15);
  font-size: 12px;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container .ui-kit-calendar-input.opened i {
  color: #44c8f9;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container .ui-kit-calendar-input span {
  display: none;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container .ui-kit-calendar-input span.opened {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container .ui-kit-calendar-cal-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  /*right: 0;*/
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #44c8f9;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 300ms linear 300ms;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container .ui-kit-calendar-cal-container.opened {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container .ui-kit-calendar-cal-container:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  right: 28px;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid #44c8f9;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container .ui-kit-calendar-cal-container .ui-kit-calendar-cal-top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container .ui-kit-calendar-cal-container .ui-kit-calendar-cal-top i {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container .ui-kit-calendar-cal-container .ui-kit-calendar-cal-top span {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 220px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container .ui-kit-calendar-cal-container .ui-kit-calendar-day-names {
  width: 100%;
  height: 23px;
  background: #35b1e2;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container .ui-kit-calendar-cal-container .ui-kit-calendar-day-names span {
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 23px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% / 7);
  height: 23px;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container .ui-kit-calendar-cal-container .ui-kit-calendar-days {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container .ui-kit-calendar-cal-container .ui-kit-calendar-days span {
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: calc(100% / 7);
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container .ui-kit-calendar-cal-container .ui-kit-calendar-days span.today {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container .ui-kit-calendar-cal-container .ui-kit-calendar-days span:hover, .ui-kit-calendar-container .ui-kit-calendar-cal-container .ui-kit-calendar-days span.is-active {
  background: #fff;
  color: #44c8f9;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container .ui-kit-calendar-input {
  border: 1px solid #aec9de;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 70px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #fcfcff;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container .ui-kit-calendar-input i {
  color: #505b71;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container .ui-kit-calendar-input.opened {
  width: 170px;
  border: 1px solid #44c8f9;
  color: #44c8f9;
  background: rgba(68, 200, 249, 0.15);
  font-size: 12px;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container .ui-kit-calendar-input.opened i {
  color: #44c8f9;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container .ui-kit-calendar-input span {
  display: none;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container .ui-kit-calendar-input span.opened {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container.danger .ui-kit-calendar-input.opened {
  color: #e2747e;
  background: rgba(226, 116, 126, 0.15);
  border: 1px solid #e2747e;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container.danger .ui-kit-calendar-input.opened i {
  color: #e2747e;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container.danger .ui-kit-calendar-cal-container {
  background: #e2747e;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container.danger .ui-kit-calendar-cal-container:after {
  border-left: 15px solid #e2747e;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container.danger .ui-kit-calendar-cal-container .ui-kit-calendar-day-names {
  background: #c72938;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container.danger .ui-kit-calendar-cal-container .ui-kit-calendar-days span:hover, .ui-kit-calendar-container.danger .ui-kit-calendar-cal-container .ui-kit-calendar-days span.is-active {
  color: #e2747e;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container.warning .ui-kit-calendar-input.opened {
  color: #f4bf4d;
  background: rgba(244, 191, 77, 0.15);
  border: 1px solid #f4bf4d;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container.warning .ui-kit-calendar-input.opened i {
  color: #f4bf4d;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container.warning .ui-kit-calendar-cal-container {
  background: #f4bf4d;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container.warning .ui-kit-calendar-cal-container:after {
  border-left: 15px solid #f4bf4d;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container.warning .ui-kit-calendar-cal-container .ui-kit-calendar-day-names {
  background: #ce910d;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container.warning .ui-kit-calendar-cal-container .ui-kit-calendar-days span:hover, .ui-kit-calendar-container.warning .ui-kit-calendar-cal-container .ui-kit-calendar-days span.is-active {
  color: #f4bf4d;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container.success .ui-kit-calendar-input.opened {
  color: #3fc59d;
  background: rgba(63, 197, 157, 0.15);
  border: 1px solid #3fc59d;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container.success .ui-kit-calendar-input.opened i {
  color: #3fc59d;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container.success .ui-kit-calendar-cal-container {
  background: #3fc59d;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container.success .ui-kit-calendar-cal-container:after {
  border-left: 15px solid #3fc59d;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container.success .ui-kit-calendar-cal-container .ui-kit-calendar-day-names {
  background: #257960;
}

.ui-kit-calendar-container.success .ui-kit-calendar-cal-container .ui-kit-calendar-days span:hover, .ui-kit-calendar-container.success .ui-kit-calendar-cal-container .ui-kit-calendar-days span.is-active {
  color: #3fc59d;
}
```

Comment: This way it is really hard to solve the problem. Better to come up with a plunker demonstrating your problem.

Comment: This is a `z-index` problem, the datepicker uses a `z-index` of 99 so it seems the rest of the form is using an higher value. What's the `z-index` of the other elements on your form like the 'Address Line 1' label.